# How to measure ping with iPerf on Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, express, iperf

I'm writing some code for my node.js/express server to allow it to run QoS tests between itself and a raspberry pi running iPerf as a server. I'm using `child_process.execFile` to call iPerf and grab its output.

I'm testing throughput, latency, jitter and packet loss. iPerf has options to allow tests of all except latency. This surprises me, as if it's measuring jitter then it must know the value of latency! I can't seem to find a way for iPerf to give me this latency result.

Am I going to have to script my own ping test?